# Unable to Install MySQL Server 8.0.17 with Error “The action ‘Install’ for product ‘MySQL Server 8.0.17’ failed”

Tags: mysql, installation

I am unable to install MySQL Server on a Windows 10 PC.  I have downloaded the installer mysql-installer-community-8.0.16.0.msi from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=486089, which I am running as an administrator.

I already have a number of products installed (Workbench, Shell, Router and some connectors).  I click on “Add”, then select “MySQL Server 8.0.17 – X64” with the default options.

The installation fails.  The log is quite long, and doesn’t contain any errors other than the final line.  I have attached the last few lines below:

1: Action 10:25:24: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 10:25:25: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {827F2F48-CCB9-4018-9AA3-0CA9FA3223E1} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.17' failed.

Any help greatly appreciated, including where I can look to find details of what the error actually is.

Regards

Geoff Olding

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue and it took me a day to figure out that there is some problem with the version itself. I went through some forums and **finally** **installed version 5.7.16 and it worked!!!**

If you have already installed other applications using mysql installer. You will see the following screen once you open it

[image]

From the above screen select the **Add** option and you will see the below screen. Then choose version 5.7.16 from the list and the rest follow the steps suggested by the installer.

[image]

If you are installing it for the first time

1. Run the mysql installer
2. Choose the custom installation option
3. Select the version 5.7.16 and the rest follow the steps suggested by the installer

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll bear it in mind if I need to try another install.  I'm afraid I can't now say how my issue was resolved.  In the end my colleague installed MySQL for me and he didn't get the same error.